# Calculate the Mean and Standard Deviation within a Range in a Data Frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying calculate the mean and standard deviation of columns within a specific row numbers in a data frame but unfortunately, I cant get it correctly since when I specify the column the `colnames` comes along with it.

Attached is the data frame I a working with:

```
structure(list(`Key Figures` = c("Jan-19", "Feb-19", "Mar-19", 
"Apr-19", "May-19", "Jun-19", "Jul-19", "Aug-19", "Sep-19", "Oct-19", 
"Nov-19", "Dec-19", "Jan-20", "Feb-20", "Mar-20", "Apr-20", "May-20", 
"Jun-20", "Jul-20", "Aug-20", "Sep-20", "Oct-20", "Nov-20", "Dec-20", 
"Jan-21", "Feb-21", "Mar-21", "Apr-21", "May-21", "Jun-21", "Jul-21", 
"Aug-21", "Sep-21", "Oct-21", "Nov-21", "Dec-21"), Qty = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 0, 10, 10, 0, 100, 0, 30, 0, 50, 70, 
280)), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

The code I wrote is giving me this output.

```
Mean <- mean(Pd_Clean[12:36,"Qty"])
```

But this of course didn't work as it has the column name in it. I understand I can create a data frame and then remove the column name and convert it into a double and perform mathematical calculation on it but I thought there should be a easier way to extract just the numbers here.

How to use the `sd()` function in this situation as well?

Any help would be appreciated.

The error is

`Mean <- mean(Pd_Clean[12:36,"Qty"]) Warning message: In mean.default(Pd_Clean[12:36, "Qty"]) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`

Comment: I don't understand, your code should work, what is the issue? What is your question? Show us your expected output.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error, the posted code works and returns `[1] 27.6`. VTC as simple error. Note: if you want a vector of column names, use `colMeans` instead. And for `sd` the loop `apply(Pd_Clean[12:36, colnames], 2, sd)` which should also be closed as a duplicate. **Am I misunderstanding the question?**

Comment: The error is probably because, when we specify Pd_Clean[12:36,"colnames"], the output which we receive will have the column name along with number right. So it would not be able to perform a mathematical function here.

Comment: "colnames" is not a column in your data frame, so this should not work. What is "colnames"? Is this just a placeholder for a column name? Are you trying to calculate the mean and SD for each numeric column?

Comment: I have hard coded the column name here. In `Pd_Clean[12:36,"Qty"]` the `Qty` is the colname. No I am trying to calculate the mean and SD of a specific colunm named `Qty` from rows 12:36.

Comment: `mean(Pd_Clean$Qty[12:36]); sd(Pd_Clean$Qty[12:36])` ? Included structure in the question is a tibble, while `Pd_Clean[12:36,"Qty"]` would return a vector in case of data.frame, for tibble it returns 1-column tibble and `mean()` & `sd()` would fail on that.

Comment: @margusl Yup. This was so obvious and I still couldn't get it. Thank you so much. Can you put this as answer so that I can mark it as complete.

Comment: It probably wasn't reproducible for others as in clean environment, `structure(list(), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))`  creates a data.frame an not tibble, so your code works as-is. Once some tidyverse packages are loaded, the same expressions returns a  tibble and code in question fails.  I.e. do not skip `library()` calls for reproducible examples.

Comment: @margusl I will keep it in my mind. Thank you.